# Redo shortcut doesn't work

Tags: shortcut

Here is strange thing: Shift+Ctrl+Z doesn't work but i still can redo through menu (edit - redo). Why is it happening? 
Blender version 2.82.7.

Comment: Perhaps the wrong order? Make sure your keys are working.

Comment: Hello :). This can happen when you switch your keyboard layout. Make sure it's still Qwerty.

Comment: @Dundun93 The order is right. Looks like keys are working, because blender reacts when i push them seperately.

Comment: @Jachym Michal But other shortcuts works fine (Ctrl+Z e.g.). Keyboard layout is English.